# Redirect to correct context when using cross context with Orbeon

Tags: grails, web-applications, orbeon, cross-context

We are developing an application with Orbeon 4.5.1
We use separated deployment, decribed as follow: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications

Separated deployment means, we have our own application, that communicate and use another application, in our case, this is Orbeon.

We are using Grails 2.2.4 for our own application, and reach it at:

```
http://hostname/ourApplication
```

It all works fine with this. Then we reach Orbeon application, by putting Orbeon afterwards, example like this:

```
http://hostname/ourApplication/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/....
```

Now we can use the functionality of Orbeon.

But when we hit a link inside Orbeon application, that should still point to Orbeons context, it points to the context for our main application instead!

So when we example hit the link: /fr/{bind('application-name-bind')}/{bind('form-name-bind')}/test, we are redirected to:

```
http://hostname/ourApplication/fr/{bind('application-name-bind')}/{bind('form-name-bind')}/test
```

Instead of the correct link:

```
http://hostname/ourApplication/orbeon/fr/{bind('application-name-bind')}/{bind('form-name-bind')}/test
```

Some places we have fixed this by putting /orbeon before the link in the Orbeon code, but this is not a solution for us, because it's very hard for us to fix all links, and when we do an upgrade of Orbeon, we have to replace all links again. And some functionality is not working right now, because of this.

I dont know whether this is a problem related to the configuration in Orbeon or Grails.

I will appreciate any help, because we have been stuck here for a while now. Please let me know if any have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri property in your properties-local.xml?

[Documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-base#TOC-oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri)

Jez

Comment: Hi Jez

Thanks for your reply.

We have already tried this, and it's doesn't work neither..

But thanks for your try, let me know if you have other ideas.